# problem with logout and get the roles from ldif fille

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-security-ldap

i have created the 3 dummy services SecurityAPI,TicketBookAPI and AccountAPI. registered all api to eureka server.i am also using login and logout features provided by spring security.I am using SecurityAPI as a gateway because i used zuul API in this service.
From SecurityAPI i am accessing TicketBookAPI and AccountAPI using zuul API.
I have Home button on TicketBookAPI and AccountAPI for redirecting to SecurityAPI and it actually redirect to SecurityAPI home then i am performing logout and it actually does logout but it does not destroy active session on SecurityAPI and I am using maximumSessions(1) feature provided by spring security.

> ```
> 1. Problem is that i could not figured out how to maintain login
> session    for all the API's and i am using login feature only in
> SecurityAPI.
>
> 2. How to get roles from LDIF file for giving resource access to client
> to perform authorization.here i am uisng ldap authentication on 
> spring boot.
>
> 3. I am also using eureka server if client know the url(Services that
> registered with eureka server with port no. under Instances
> currently registered with Eureka) from eureka dashboard, they can
> easily access that Services without knowing us.so how can i protect
> that.
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504

Comment: i hope its a correct question format.